# Template Tag "template_directory" pulling wrong path

Tags: theme-development

I'm working on a theme index.php and it seems that when I use the "template_directory" it is not actually pulling the url path of the file, but instead is just pulling the main domain name. So instead of

```
 http://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/images/pic.jpg
```

its pulling the domain url and showing this

```
http://example.com/images/pic.jpg
```

I don't understand why it's doing this, since the index.php file is actually in the right directory. (which is inside the theme folder). There is the index.php file that is in the wordpress directory... but I don't understand why it would conflict with the themes index.php file.

Comment: Can you post the *actual code you're using*? Otherwise, it will be nearly impossible to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the exact path of image which is placed in http://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/images/pic.jpg in your theme.

All you have to use below code:

1. To show image

> ```
> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pic.jpg" />
> ```

Comment: The `bloginfo()` template tag *already echoes* its result; you don't need to echo it explicitly. `bloginfo()` *echoes* its result, while `get_bloginfo()` *returns* its result. Also, I strongly recommend using `get_template_directory_uri()` in place of `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one of two things:

1. You're not using the correct template tag.

   Are you using `get_template_directory_uri()` or something else?
2. You're not *echoing* the result

   If you're using `get_template_directory_uri()`, you have to *echo* it; e.g. this:

   /images/pic.jpg">Link

Will result in:

```
<a href="/images/pic.jpg">Link</a>
```

So, you need to do this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/pic.jpg">Link</a>
```

Which will result in:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/pic.jpg">Link</a>
```